# Remove class from element and add to next element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of links, one has the class active.

On my next button click id like to remove the class from the current element and add it to the next only I cant seem to get it to add?

Ive made a fiddle to hopefully explain my problem, any help would be great, thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/h6D4k/

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    $('ul.pagination').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
    $('ul.pagination').find('a.active').next('a').addClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: use a variable ? `foo = $().find(); foo.remove; foo.next().add`, or something (or chain it)

Comment: By the way, what do you want to happen when you reach the bottom of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it this way, preventing the action from doing anything on the last li as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/h6D4k/6/

```
$('.next').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("ul.pagination a.active").parent().is(":last-child")) return;
    $('ul.pagination a.active').removeClass('active').parent().next().find("a").addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 10):

One of the jQuery most usable conveniencies is that its methods are (usually) chainable - in other words, they return the very object they are called from. So you can simply write this:

```
$('ul.pagination').find('a.active').removeClass('active').closest('li')
                  .next('li').find('a').addClass('active');
```

... as it's `<li>` elements that should be 'nexted', not `<a>` ones. But in fact, you shouldn't probably discard 'active' altogether if it's the last element in question:

```
var $a      = $('ul.pagination').find('a.active'),
    $li     = $a.closest('li'),
    $nextLi = $li.next('li');

if ($nextLi.length) {
   $a.removeClass('active');
   $nextLi.find('a').addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because once you've done this...

```
$('ul.pagination').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
```

There is no more `a.active` - the `active` classname has been removed from that element. So repeating the same selector...

```
$('ul.pagination').find('a.active')//...
```

... will select nothing.

Chain it all together instead.

```
$('ul.pagination').find('a.active').removeClass('active').next('a').addClass('active');
```

---

You have a second problem. According to the jQuery API for `next()`, it will:

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

You're not trying to get the following sibling:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a class="one active" href="#">X</a></li>
    <li><a class="two" href="#">X</a></li>
    <li><a class="three" href="#">X</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="" class="next">Next</a>
<a href="" class="prev">Prev</a>
```

You're trying to get the next `<a>` in the whole document. That's more challenging - and I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: @Jack - Ya, I caught that and started updating my answer. Not sure what the best general solution is for them...

Answer (score 3):

This is actually what you want based on your html structure in you fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/h6D4k/1/

```
$('ul.pagination').find('a.active').removeClass('active').parent()
                  .next().find('a').addClass('active');
```

Comment: I think they want the next-ing to continue outside the `<ul>` - which this won't.

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen Yeah, that might need to be a new question though. I figure he's gotten some new knowledge out of all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors in your code:

1. Once removed, the active class can't be found anymore
2. your a tags are nested in li tags so next() doesn't work as you expect

To simplify things, you could attach the active class to the li tags.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h6D4k/7/

Code:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
  $('ul.pagination').find('li.active').removeClass('active')
                    .next().addClass('active');
  return false;
});
```